# How many addons can put in my world for Minecraft in the Nintendo Switch

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch, minecraft-addons

this is my question: I have a single old world that weighs 56 MB, I recently bought and downloaded some free addons on the market and decided to add them all to my world, I checked the storage section and it says that in Resource Packs it weighs 46.9 MB and The Behavior Pack is 28.2 MB, the problem is that the world ends up closing every time I try to start it due to an error, I suppose it is due to the heavier add-ons, because removing them normally improves for a while but this error continues to appear after for a while, but I wonder if there is a space limit for add-ons or is it simply because the Nintendo Switch version is not the most stable, if anyone knows why this happens, I would appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: In theory, it would be "as many as you can fit two copies on your storage" (one in the world, another for the download), and the system doesn't die due to overload like with every other edition. There isn't a fixed number since addons come in many shapes and sizes. You could probably run a couple of addons from the store on a switch fine, but then struggle to run [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoEQ_dbItxI) even just by itself.